# How to play .wav file from another folder? Done on Visual Studio 2010 c++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wav, playsound

I'm doing a project that requires the user to type in the phonetic sounds.

For example, **th**. Then the program will play a wave file that produce **th** sound. 
As there are many different wave files for a phonetic sounds, I have decided to group them into separate files, which means it would not be in the same folder of the .exe directory. In this case how do I play the sound that is from another file?

Here is the segment that I thought could work but it didnt.. Please help me!

```
FILENAME1 = strcat(text_data, ".wav");
FILENAME2 = strcat("wav" ,FILENAME1);
printf ("%s", FILENAME2);
PlaySound(TEXT(FILENAME2), NULL, SND_SYNC);
```

The text_data contains what the user types.such as "th". and the applicaiton plays the **th.wav** file Is it possible to play it from another folder? So that I can group various wav files into categories.

Then it will be something like this:;

Debug (contains the .exe file) --> consonants --> th.wav (this is the one I want to play but it will not be in the same directory as the .exe file.

Please help me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to give the complete path. For instance, if the files are in Debug\Sounds\SomeSound.wav, you will have to provide Sounds\SomeSound.wav as path.

Edit: You can use '+' operator to concatenate multiple strings. It should look like:

```
"Folder_Name\\" + text_data + ".wav"
```

You can also take a look at std::stringstream to do this job.

Comment: hmmm, how do you include the complete path in the code? i do not know how to include them in the code above.

Comment: Instead of just adding ".wav" to text_data, you need to add directory name as well before the text.

Comment: do you mean something like this? 

FILENAME1 = strcat(\Debug\Sounds\,text_data, ".wav");

pls pardon me because i just started out learning programming thanks!

Comment: FILENAME1 = strcat(text_data, ".wav");
       FILENAME2 = strcat("consonants\\" ,FILENAME1);
       printf ("%s", FILENAME2); 
       PlaySound(TEXT(FILENAME2), NULL, SND_SYNC);

I tried doing it this way. but when i run the .exe file, it says there is error though i can compile it. is the code above correct?

Comment: it is a pop up window that says that my program has stopped working and windows is checking for solution.

Comment: when i put this only,
FILENAME1 = strcat(text_data, ".wav");
printf ("%s", FILENAME1);

it works well